# Cordova 9 - minimal supported Android API-Levels / Android version?

Tags: cordova

What is the minimal supported Android API-Levels / Android version of Cordova 9.X?

There is no information about it on page https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/

Thanks, Pavel

Comment: Cordova Android is still on 8.X, 9.X is not even developed yet. I doubt there is any reliable information on what Android versions it will support.